# Is it possible to insert SSI into javascript in a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, ssi

As I don't know javascript at all, I'm wondering if it's possible to insert some SSI into javascript in a PHP file. I've got a bit of script going to preload some images, and I'd like to set it up so that some images always get preloaded across my entire site (via the SSI) of which I may add to over time, while allowing me to add individual images as needed page by page. It works fine in my HTML files, but not it my PHP files.

Here's what I've got in my HTML files which works just fine:

```
<script>
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }
    preload([
        <!--#include virtual="/grabbag/preload-images.html" -->
        '/images/image-1.png',
        '/images/image-2.png'
    ]);
</script>
```

But this doesn't work in my PHP files, the SSI getting replaced with nothing but empty text:

```
<script>
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }
    preload([
        <?php include("/grabbag/preload-images.php"); ?>
        '/images/image-1.png',
        '/images/image-2.png'
    ]);
</script>
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the text is injected before the document is served to the client, assuming the syntax in JavaScript is valid, this should work.

Comment: in php, use json_encode to make valid js lists. you can slice 1,-1 to get a valid array fragment from a json array.

Comment: Thanks @Derek 朕會功夫 you were right. I must have missed something, as the HTML version does work. However, the PHP version doesn't work. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: So what does the resulting HTML source code, in the browser, look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP include is absolute. It begins with a / and therefore it'll look in the root (the up most path) and tries to traverse down. Change it to a relative one or the correct absolute one and a it'll work

Comment: Ah, geez, you're right. Stupid me. Although I copied and pasted the correct include for usage in PHP files, I incorrectly copied and pasted the path from my HTML SSI. So this wasn't a javascript issue at all, but a dumb-ass me issue. I added the requisite `../../`. Thanks! (As an aside, I don't see why the `/` works in my HTML but not the PHP. Do I have to include `/public_html/` or something?)

Comment: You can find out the full path of your php file using http://php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php. So you could also do smth like include realpath(null)."/"relative/path/to/file.ext";

Comment: The / in your html ssi points to your document root (eg your public_html folder), whereas in PHP it points to the the file system root folder. That is simply why it doesn't work. I don't know about your PHP config, but it could be that you have your document root in your include path and if so, you can simply omit the leading slash from your include and it should work aswell